# How long will it take to learn Action Script 3 in Adobe flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I know php mysql , javascript , jquery very well. I have never touced flash.
Now  have to do website in complete flash with action scripting.

Keeping flash animation and scripting separate. How much time it will take for me to build
e.g.

```
1)Simple page with 1 column layout like , header , navigation bar , content.
2)The navigation items will be loaded from database using xml and flash
3)The content will also load from database depending upon navigation item clicked
```

How much time for inserting flash objects and how much time for scripting. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the skills you have already, you would be used to how Object Oriented Programming looks and works.

For what you request, I dare say it would not take you long to understand how to create code to feed from XML.

I always find that best learning when it comes to code, is to get a free example, take it apart, put it back together again. Research those methods to learn all relevant information. Instead of getting a book and trying to master the entire AS3 language, learn just what you need for your project.

[FlashMo](http://www.flashmo.com/) is an excellent portal with lots of free resources when it comes to interactive flash content.

The main concept you will have to get down to a T, is parsing XML and loading it into your Flash project, which is heavily documented in examples and tutorials.

As a PHP and mySQL programmer, naturally you'll create a PHP page to pull data from your DB and auto=generate it as an XML file.

Time wise, this should not take you long depending on the complexity of your Flash website.

Answer (score 1):

Well Javascript and Actionscript3 are both part of the ECMAScript family although actionscript 3 didn't upgraded thus far.

its still follows the ecmascript 4 spec...

therefore there are some differences but it's super easy to switch between those languages because the concept is the same.

it's like British English and American English.

both of them are very similar but there are some minor differences